# How to email a range of data via google sheet script?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a code like below, pls suggest how to get the values that I have to mail.
it fails when I run the command with the error {TypeError: sheet.getRange(...).getvalues is not a function (line 14, file "macros")}

```
  function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange("A2").getvalues();
  var message = sheet.getrange("B2:B3").getvalues(); 
  var subject = sheet.getrange("C2").getvalues();
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
```

in google Sheet data:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01egC.jpg)

Pls suggest a code which would help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this working script:

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 2; i < lastRow+1 ; i++ ) {

    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var subject = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var message = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script uses JavaScript which is case sensitive.

- Instead of `getvalues` you should use `getValues`
- Instead of `getrange` you shoulde use `getRange`